# Error compiling for board Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, compilation-errors, neopixel

I am relatively new to Arduino and I am trying to code some neo pixels and every time I try to verify my code this error comes up:

> Arduino: 1.8.12 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Uno"
>
> loading libs from /Users/erinshankland/Documents/Arduino/libraries: reading dir >/Users/erinshankland/Documents/Arduino/libraries: open >/Users/erinshankland/Documents/Arduino/libraries: operation not permitted
>
> Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.
>
> This report would have more information with
> "Show verbose output during compilation"
> option enabled in File -> Preferences.

this is my code:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN        6

 

#define NUMPIXELS 15

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRBW + NEO_KHZ800);

 

// this constant won't change:

const int  btnRed = 2;  // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to

const int  btnBlue = 3;  // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to

const int  btnGreen = 4;  // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to

const int  btnPurple = 5;  // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to

 

 

void setup() {

  randomSeed(analogRead(A0));

  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  pinMode(btnRed, INPUT);

  pinMode(btnBlue, INPUT);

  pinMode(btnGreen, INPUT);

  pinMode(btnPurple, INPUT);

 

  // initialize the LED as an output:

  // initialize serial communication:

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pixels.begin(); // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)

    pixels.clear(); // Set all pixel colors to 'off'

    pixels.show();

    delay(1000);

 

}

 

void loop() {

if (digitalRead(btnRed)==HIGH){

    rndRed();

  delay(100);

}

 

if (digitalRead(btnBlue)==HIGH){

    rndBlue();

  delay(100);

}

if (digitalRead(btnGreen)==HIGH){

    rndGreen();

  delay(100);

}

 

if (digitalRead(btnPurple)==HIGH){

    rndPurple();

  delay(100);

}

}

 

 

void rndRed() {

  int led = random(0, 15);

  pixels.setPixelColor(led, pixels.Color(255, 0, 0,0));

  pixels.show();   // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.

  delay(500);

}

 

void rndBlue() {

  int led = random(0, 9);

  pixels.setPixelColor(led, pixels.Color(0, 0, 255,0));

  pixels.show();   // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.

  delay(500);

 

}

 

void rndGreen() {

  int led = random(0, 9);

  pixels.setPixelColor(led, pixels.Color(0, 255, 0,0));

  pixels.show();   // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.

  delay(500);

 

}

 

void rndPurple() {

  int led = random(0, 9);

  pixels.setPixelColor(led, pixels.Color(171, 0, 255, 0));

  pixels.show();   // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.

  delay(500);

}
```

I am using a new library for the neo pixels but this has been downloaded and updated.
Hopefully someone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

> loading libs from /Users/erinshankland/Documents/Arduino/libraries: reading dir 
>   /Users/erinshankland/Documents/Arduino/libraries: open 
>   /Users/erinshankland/Documents/Arduino/libraries: operation not permitted

This is not an Arduino problem but an OS problem.

Either your `/Users/erinshankland/Documents/Arduino/libraries` is not accessible by your user (check the permissions) or it's not a directory.

You can try, from a terminal:

```
sudo chown -R erinshankland /Users/erinshankland/Documents/Arduino/libraries
chmod -R 755 /Users/erinshankland/Documents/Arduino/libraries
```

which will reset ownership and file permissions on the directory and everything underneath it.

If not, then delete your libraries folder (which may in fact be a file, not a folder) and recreate it and repopulate it with your desired libraries.

Comment: Thank you this worked! looked like it was a problem with my libraries!